# Как в приложении Win32 определить - на котором объекте D2D1PathGeometry была нажата левая клавиша мыши, если в окне несколько таких объектов?

Tags: winapi, graphics, события, visual-c++

В своём приложении Win32 на Visual C++, я создал два объекта D2D1PathGeometry. Вот они ниже:

```
// Функция для рисования.
HRESULT MyClass::OnRender()
{
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        . . . . .
    // Создать первый объект (m_pDirect2dFactory это экземпляр ID2D1Factory, созданный ранее).
    hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreatePathGeometry(&m_pMyGeom_1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
                // pSink это экземпляр ID2D1GeometrySink, созданный ранее.
        hr = pMyGeom_1->Open(&pSink);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            pSink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);
            // Добавить дугу.
            pSink->BeginFigure(m_InitialPoint_1, D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);
            pSink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(m_EndPoint_1, m_Radius, 0.0f, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
            pSink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
            // Добавить линию.
            pSink->BeginFigure(m_InitialPoint_1, D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW);
            pSink->AddLine(m_EndPoint_1);
            pSink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
        }
        hr = pSink->Close();
    }
    // Создать второй объект.
    hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreatePathGeometry(&m_pMyGeom_2);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pMyGeom_2->Open(&pSink);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            pSink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);
            // Добавить дугу.
            pSink->BeginFigure(m_InitialPoint_2, D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);
            pSink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(m_BackEndPoint_2, m_Radius, 0.0f, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
            pSink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
            // Добавить линию.
            pSink->BeginFigure(m_InitialPoint_2, D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW);
            pSink->AddLine(m_EndPoint_2);
            pSink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
        }
        hr = pSink->Close();
    }
        . . . . .
        SafeRelease(&pSink);
    // Начать отрисовку (m_pRenderTarget это созданный ранее экземпляр ID2D1HwndRenderTarget).
    m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        . . . . .
    m_pRenderTarget->FillGeometry(m_pMyGeom_1, m_pMidnightBlueBrush);
    m_pRenderTarget->FillGeometry(m_pMirror_2, m_pMidnightBlueBrush);
        . . . . .
    hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
}
```

Затем, я добавил сообщения WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE и WM_LBUTTONUP в WindowProc и определил для них соответствующие обработчики: OnLButtonDown(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags), OnMouseMove(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags) and OnLButtonUp().

```
// Нажата левая клавиша мыши.
void MyClass::OnLButtonDown(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags)
{
    // Получить координаты мыши в момент нажатия её левой клавиши.
    POINT mouseLocation;
    mouseLocation.x = pixelX;
    mouseLocation.y = pixelY;
    // Если курсор мыши наведён на объект ID2D1PathGeometry в окне приложения:
     if (DragDetect(m_hwnd, mouseLocation))
     {
         // Перевести физические пиксели в системные DPI и запомнить как текущие координаты мыши.
         ptMouse = PixelsToDips(pixelX, pixelY);
         SetCapture(m_hwnd);
         // Приготовиться к drag-and-drop объекта геометрии ID2D1PathGeometry.
        f_DragMode = true;
     }
}
// Пользователь перемещает мышь.
void MyClass::OnMouseMove(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags)
{
     // Проверить, нажата ли левая клавиша мыши.
     if ((flags & MK_LBUTTON) && f_DragMode)
     {
         const D2D1_POINT_2F dips = PixelsToDips(pixelX, pixelY);

         // Как определить над каким из 2-х объектов геометрии ID2D1PathGeometry
         // в окне приложения находится курсор мыши? !!!НЕ ЗНАЮ!!!
         // Поэтому дальше в этом обработчике - ничего существенного не написал.

         // Сохранить текущие координаты мыши.
         ptMouse = dips;
         // Инициировать перерисовку окна.
         InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
     }
}
// Пользователь отпустил левую клавишу мыши.
void MyClass::OnLButtonUp()
{
      ReleaseCapture();
      if (!f_DragMode)
          f_DragMode = false;
}
```

Как определить в программе - над какой из геометрией в окне находится мышь (если DragDetect вернула true)? Пояснений к этому я не нашёл нигде. До этого мне практически не приходилось писать код для событий мыши, да и с Direct2D  я знаком только 7-й день. Любая помощь будет принята с благодарностью.

Comment: Ну неужели нет знающих людей и некому подсказать? Пожалуйста, мне срочно надо.

Comment: А [`FillContainsPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) не сработало?

Comment: А она не чуствительна к тому, как отрисовывается геометрия - с помощью DrawGeometry я рисую только контур, а с помощью FillGeometry ещё и закрашивается внутреннее пространство геометрии. (Прошу прощения, но занимаюсь Direct2D только 7-й день.)

Comment: Ну да. Но чтобы определить, относится ли точка к данному объекту, вам по идее должно быть всё равно, лежит ли точка на границе или внутри. Потому что иначе вы будете заставлять юзера попадать точно в линию, а это как-то не то.

Comment: Сейчас ещё один пост оформлю...